# Popup message in python requires code to converted to HTML/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, pandas, folium

Say I have a lot of rows which contain in a column a name that name may contain certain characters say spaces, special characters.

I have coded so far using the folium library and pandas that a circle appears at a particular longitude and latitude on a map.

What I do not understand is, that when I want to code there to be a popup message such that when I hover my mouse over the circle the name I mentioned earlier pops up, this requires the string to be converted into Javascript/HTML.

Can someone explain to me or link documentation that explains why and the process/built-in code that gets executed in order for this action to take place (the conversion from python string to JavaScript/HTML).

This is the code I have written for this bit:

> for _, row in df.iterrows():
> folium.CircleMaker(
> location=[row.LAT,row.LON],
> radius=3,
> popup=row.NAME
> )

Comment: I checked the example in the official reference with a [notebook viewer](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/Popups.ipynb), and from this example, I don't think it necessarily has to be HTML.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.